# Plotting weights vs iteration of a neural network

Tags: math, neural-network, deep-learning

I would like to build a deep learning visualization tool.

But i'm stuck on the plot of weights vs iteration. Typically, I want to do this: [mean magnitude weights vs iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1129M.png).

This photo is taken from this website [visualization tool](https://deeplearning4j.org/visualization).
If I understand well, the document says that this is the log of the mean magnitude of the weights.

So, for each layer of my neural network, I will have a curve?
But I'm not sure if the formula to compute one point of one curve is : [mean magnitude formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brjQF.gif).

Where w1, w2, ... wn are the weights of one layer given a specified iteration.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each layer will have its own curve. Maybe an important point to recognize when building a deep learning visualization tool is *why* would someone want to visualize mean magnitude weight vs iteration.

The answer is: to see if the model is overfitting. Each layer of the model will converge (hopefully, not guaranteed) to some fixed point magnitude. The magnitude of each layer will be different based on the type of layer, the size of the model, etc. As such, it is only interesting to view the mean magnitude on a per layer basis. If the magnitude of a layer (especially the last) begins getting large, then the network is likely overfitting to its training data.

To answer the question about the formula, the goal is the find the average (mean) weight of every weight in that layer. So yes, sum up the weights for a layer, divide by the number of weights in that layer, and maybe take the log of that to make the scale easier to read (though that last is a design decision more than it is a mathematical decision, if anything we would assume that the weights are gaussian distribution and a natural log would make more sense than log base 10).